# Position arrow above from output to specific block

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}   
\usepackage{cancel}

\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes,
                calc}
\tikzset{
block/.style={
  draw, 
  fill=blue!20, 
  rectangle, 
  minimum height=3em, 
  minimum width=1em,
  text centered, 
  text width=2cm
  },
sum/.style={
  draw, 
  fill=blue!20, 
  circle, 
  },
input/.style={coordinate},
output/.style={coordinate},
pinstyle/.style={
  pin edge={to-,thin,black}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]

\centering

\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em, fill=blue!20]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, circle, node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=2cm, thick,node/.style={circle,draw}]
    % We start by placing the blocks
    \node [input, name=input] {};
    \node [input, name=velocities, above of=input] {};
    \node [sum, right of=input] (sum) {};
    \node [block, right of=sum] (controller) {\textlatin{P-Controller}};
    \node [sum, right of=controller, node distance=2cm] (vel_sum) {};
    \node [block, right of=vel_sum] (jacobian) {$\text{\textlatin{J}}^{-1}$};
    \node [block, right of=jacobian,
            node distance=2cm] (integrator) {$\int$};
    % We draw an edge between the controller and system block to 
    % calculate the coordinate u. We need it to place the measurement block. 
    %\draw [->] (controller) -- node[name=u] {$U$} (system);
    \node [output, right of=integrator] (output) {};
    \node [block, below of=vel_sum] (fwd_kin) {$\Gamma(.)$};

    % Once the nodes are placed, connecting them is easy. 
    \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node[pos=0.1] {$p_{r},\omega_{r} \ +$} (sum);
    \draw [draw,->] (velocities) -| node[pos=0.01] {$\dot{p}_r,\dot{\omega}_r$} node[pos=0.9] {$+$} (vel_sum);
    \draw [->] (sum) -- node {$e$} (controller);
    \draw [->] (controller) -- node {$+$} (vel_sum);
    \draw [->] (vel_sum) -- node {$ee_{vel}$} (jacobian);
    \draw [->] (jacobian) -- node {$\dot{q}$} (integrator);
    \draw [->] (integrator) -- node [name=q] {$q$}(output);
    \draw [->] (q) |- (fwd_kin);
    \draw [->] (fwd_kin) -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$} 
        node [near end] {$p,\omega$} (sum);
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Control Scheme}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I have written the above script and I would like to modify it in a way such that the painted-black arrow appears. I have spent some time on it, can't find the proper solution and that is why I ask here. Any ideas would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MWE hase many issues:

- picture elements styles are define twice
- some Ti*k*Z libraries are load twice
- why you load `chains` and `quotes` libraries and then not used them in your image code?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes,
                }
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\tikzset{
  arr/.style = {-{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]},semithick},
block/.style = {draw, fill=blue!20,
                minimum height=3em, minimum width=2em,},
  dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0pt},
  sum/.style = {circle, draw, fill=blue!20},
every edge/.style = {draw, arr},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\small}
        }


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=12mm and 11mm,
  start chain = going right 
                        ]
% main branch
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain}]
\coordinate (in-1); 
\node[sum]      (sum-1) {};
\node[block]    (cntrl) {\textlatin{P-Controller}};
\node[sum]      (sum-2) {};
\node[block]    (jacobian)   {$\mathrm{J}^{-1}$};
\node[block]    (int)   {$\int$};
\node[dot]      (dot)   {};
\coordinate (out);
    \end{scope}
\coordinate[above=of in-1] (in-2);
\node[block, below=of sum-2] (fwd_kin) {$\Gamma(\cdot)$};
% edges
\draw   (in-1)  edge["{$p_{r},\omega_{r}\ +$}"] (sum-1)
        (sum-1) edge["$e$"]                     (cntrl)
        (cntrl) edge[pos=0.9, "$+$"]            (sum-2)
        (sum-2) edge["$ee_{\mathrm{vel}}$"]     (jacobian)
        (jacobian) edge["$\dot{q}$"]            (int)
        (int)   edge[pos=0.25, "$q$"]           (out);
\draw[->]   (dot)       |- (fwd_kin);
\draw[->]   (dot)       |- (in-2 -| jacobian) -- (jacobian);
\draw[->]   (fwd_kin)   -| node[pos=0.95, left] {$-$}
                           node [near end, left] {$p,\omega$} (sum-1);
\draw[->]   (in-2)  node[above right]   {$\dot{p}_r,\dot{\omega}_r$} -|
                    node[pos=0.85,right] {$+$}   (sum-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Control Scheme}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes,
                calc}
\tikzset{
block/.style={
  draw, 
  fill=blue!20, 
  rectangle, 
  minimum height=3em, 
  minimum width=1em,
  text centered, 
  text width=2cm
  },
sum/.style={
  draw, 
  fill=blue!20, 
  circle, 
  },
input/.style={coordinate},
output/.style={coordinate},
pinstyle/.style={
  pin edge={to-,thin,black}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em, fill=blue!20]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, circle, node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=2cm, thick,node/.style={circle,draw}]
    % We start by placing the blocks
    \node [input, name=input] {};
    \node [input, name=velocities, above of=input] {};
    \node [sum, right of=input] (sum) {};
    \node [block, right of=sum] (controller) {P-Controller};
    \node [sum, right of=controller, node distance=2cm] (vel_sum) {};
    \node [block, right of=vel_sum] (jacobian) {${J}^{-1}$};
    \node [block, right of=jacobian,
            node distance=2cm] (integrator) {$\int$};
    % We draw an edge between the controller and system block to 
    % calculate the coordinate u. We need it to place the measurement block. 
    %\draw [->] (controller) -- node[name=u] {$U$} (system);
    \node [output, right of=integrator] (output) {};
    \node [block, below of=vel_sum] (fwd_kin) {$\Gamma(.)$};

    % Once the nodes are placed, connecting them is easy. 
    \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node[pos=0.1] {$p_{r},\omega_{r} \ +$} (sum);
    \draw [draw,->] (velocities) -| node[pos=0.01] {$\dot{p}_r,\dot{\omega}_r$} node[pos=0.9] {$+$} (vel_sum);
    \draw [->] (sum) -- node {$e$} (controller);
    \draw [->] (controller) -- node {$+$} (vel_sum);
    \draw [->] (vel_sum) -- node {$ee_{vel}$} (jacobian);
    \draw [->] (jacobian) -- node {$\dot{q}$} (integrator);
    \draw [->] (integrator) -- node [name=q] {$q$}(output);
    \draw [->] (q) |- (fwd_kin);
    \draw [->] (fwd_kin) -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$} 
        node [near end] {$p,\omega$} (sum);
\draw[->]  (q) -- +(0,1) -| (jacobian); %added
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Block diagram]

Comment: Why you define picture elements twice? The second, written in obsolete syntax `\tikzstyle{...}=` should be deleted.

Comment: When there are so many issues with OP's code, I only correct stuff until it compiles and then add the answer.